# Nuxt application local development server constantly reloading

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt ^2.15.8 application which is constantly reloading after I run `yarn dev`.

The console will show a message like `↻ Updated 1647868577626`, and then the application is rebuilt, as if I just run `yarn dev`. This happens constantly over and over, without me doing any changes in the code.

I googled a bit, and found applications like gitkraken might be modifying the content of the .git folder and that could trigger a reload.

So I keep gitkraken closed.

I also added these lines to my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
watchers: {
  webpack: {
    ignored: [
      '**/*.{md,log,prettierignore,prettierrc,stylelintignore,npmrc,gitignore}',
      '**/.git/**',
    ],
  },
},
```

That doesn't fix the issue though

My main question is: what would the line `↻ Updated 1647868577626` mean, and what could be causing it? I get the feeling that if I want to solve my problem, I need to answer that question.

Edit: this is my full `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

// TODO Migrate from dotenv to runtime config https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/
import { config } from 'dotenv'

config()

// eslint-disable-next-line import/first
import { exportSitePayload, getSitePayload } from './scripts/prepare-for-build'
// eslint-disable-next-line import/first

process.env.NUXT_TARGET_MODE
  = process.env.NUXT_TARGET_MODE || (process.env.NETLIFY ? 'static' : 'server')

const isProd
  = /prod/i.test(process.env.NODE_ENV)
  || process.env.NETLIFY
  || (process.env.HEROKU && process.env.PP_ENV === 'production')
const isStaging
  = !isProd
  && (/stag/i.test(process.env.NODE_ENV) || (process.env.HEROKU && process.env.PP_ENV === 'staging'))
const isDev = !(isProd || isStaging)

export default async function() {
  await exportSitePayload({
    ...(process.env.STATIC_HOST ? { staticHost: process.env.STATIC_HOST } : {}),
    ...(process.env.HEROKU ? { all: true } : {}),
  })
  return {
    ssr: process.env.SSR !== 'false',
    target: process.env.NUXT_TARGET_MODE,
    components: [
      { path: '~/components/', pathPrefix: false },
      { path: '~/components', pathPrefix: true, level: 1 },
    ],
    env: {
      SANITY_PROJECT_ID: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
      SANITY_PROJECT_DATASET: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_DATASET,
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      apiBaseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
      forceAPIBaseURL: process.env.FORCE_API_BASE_URL,
      ppEnv: process.env.PP_ENV,
      archivedMode: process.env.ARCHIVED_MODE,
      archivedModeLiveLink: process.env.ARCHIVED_MODE_LIVE_LINK,
      attendeeAPILinkedInCallback: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_LINKEDIN_CALLBACK,
      attendeeAPILogout: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_LOGOUT,
      attendeeAPIVerifyLogincode: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_VERIFY_LOGINCODE,
      attendeeAPIMagicLinkRequest: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_MAGIC_LINK_REQUEST,
      attendeeAPIRegister: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_REGISTER,
      attendeeAPIUserInfo: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_USER_INFO,
      devDisableCache: process.env.DEV_DISABLE_CACHE,
      eventAPIDetails: process.env.EVENT_ENDPOINT_DETAILS,
      eventAPIBadge: process.env.EVENT_ENDPOINT_BADGE,
      liveEventAPIStage: process.env.LIVE_EVENT_ENDPOINT_STAGE,
      liveEventAPIChat: process.env.LIVE_EVENT_ENDPOINT_CHAT,
      orderAPICustomer: process.env.ORDER_ENDPOINT_CUSTOMER,
      orderAPICart: process.env.ORDER_ENDPOINT_CART,
      orderAPIInfo: process.env.ORDER_ENDPOINT_INFO,
      orderAPIInvoice: process.env.ORDER_ENDPOINT_INVOICE,
      paymentAPIMethods: process.env.PAYMENT_API_METHODS,
      productAPIInfo: process.env.PRODUCT_ENDPOINT_INFO,
      staticHost: process.env.STATIC_HOST,
      streamChatAPIKey: process.env.STREAM_CHAT_API_KEY,
      streamChatAPPId: process.env.STREAM_CHAT_APP_ID,
      ticketAPIDetails: process.env.TICKET_ENDPOINT_DETAILS,
      ticketAPIList: process.env.TICKET_ENDPOINT_LIST,
      userAPIOrders: process.env.USER_ENDPOINT_ORDERS,
      videoAPIDetails: process.env.VIDEO_API_ENDPOINT_DETAILS,
      videoAPILists: process.env.VIDEO_API_ENDPOINT_LISTS,
      videoAPIUploadInfo: process.env.VIDEO_API_ENDPOINT_UPLOAD_INFO,
      isProd,
      isStaging,
      isDev,
    },
    /*
     ** Headers of the page
     */
    head: {
      meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        {
          hid: 'viewport',
          name: 'viewport',
          content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
        },
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://use.typekit.net/fag0imi.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/theme.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/static_theme.css' },
      ],
    },
    /*
     ** Customize the progress-bar color
     */
    loading: { color: 'var(--color-primary-500)' },
    /*
     ** Global CSS
     */
    css: [],
    /*
     ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
     */
    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/vuelidate.js',
      '~/plugins/filters.js',
      '~/plugins/lazyload.js',
      '~/plugins/reactive-provide.js',
      '~/plugins/vue-form-wizard',
      '~/plugins/vue-phone-number-input',
      '~/plugins/vue-selectize',
      '~/plugins/sanity-block-vue-component.js',
      '~/plugins/youtube.client.js',
      '~/plugins/v-tooltip.js',
      '~/plugins/axios.js',
      { src: 'plugins/vue-typer.client.js', ssr: false },
    ],
    /*
     ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
     */
    buildModules: [
      '@nuxt/postcss8',
      // https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/
      '@nuxt/typescript-build',
      // https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup
      '@nuxtjs/composition-api/module',
      // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
      '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
      // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
      '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
      '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    ],
    /*
     ** Nuxt.js modules
     */
    modules: [
      '@nuxtjs/axios',
      [
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
        {
          manifest: false,
          icon: false,
          workbox: {
            runtimeCaching: [
              {
                urlPattern: 'https://a.storyblok.com/.*',
                handler: 'CacheFirst',
              },
              {
                urlPattern: 'https://img2.storyblok.com/.*',
                handler: 'CacheFirst',
              },
              {
                urlPattern: 'https://cdn.sanity.io/.*',
                handler: 'CacheFirst',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
      [
        'storyblok-nuxt',
        {
          accessToken: process.env.STORYBLOK_ACCESS_TOKEN,
          cacheProvider: 'memory',
        },
      ],
      'nuxt-webfontloader',
      'portal-vue/nuxt',
      '@nuxtjs/proxy',
      '@nuxtjs/sentry',
    ],

    ...(isProd || isStaging
      ? {
        sentry: {
          dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DNS, // Enter your project's DSN here
          // Additional Module Options go here
          // https://sentry.nuxtjs.org/sentry/options
          tracing: {
            tracesSampleRate: isProd ? 0.2 : 1.0,
            vueOptions: {
              tracing: true,
              tracingOptions: {
                hooks: ['mount', 'update'],
                timeout: 2000,
                trackComponents: true,
              },
            },
            browserOptions: {},
          },
          config: {
            // Add native Sentry config here
            // https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/vue/configuration/options/
            environment: isProd ? 'production' : 'staging',
            debug: !isProd,
          },
        },
      }
      : {}),

    ...(!/prod/i.test(process.env.NODE_ENV) && !process.env.NETLIFY
      ? {
        proxy: {
          '/.netlify/functions': {
            target: process.env.API_ORIGIN,
          },
        },
      }
      : {}),

    ...(/prod/i.test(process.env.NODE_ENV) || process.env.NETLIFY || process.env.HEROKU
      ? {}
      : {
        server: {
          https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '.tls/key.pem')),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '.tls/cert.pem')),
          },
        },
      }),

    axios: {
      credentials: true,
      baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    },
    auth: {
      cookie: {
        cookie: {
          name: 'frontend_love_account_state',
        },
        token: {
          required: false,
          type: false,
        },
        user: {
          property: '',
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_MAGIC_LINK_REQUEST,
            method: 'post',
          },
          logout: { url: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_LOGOUT, method: 'post' },
          user: { url: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_USER_INFO, method: 'get' },
        },
      },
      loginCode: {
        scheme: 'local',
        token: {
          required: false,
          type: false,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_VERIFY_LOGINCODE,
            method: 'post',
          },
          user: { url: process.env.ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT_USER_INFO, method: 'get' },
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          autoFetch: false,
        },
      },
      plugins: ['~/plugins/auth.js'],
    },
    /*
     ** nuxt-webfontloader Options
     */
    webfontloader: {
      google: {
        families: ['Merriweather:300,400,700', 'Rubik:300,400,500', 'Odibee+Sans'],
      },
    },
    /*
     ** Build configuration
     */
    build: {
      quiet: false,
      /*
       ** You can extend webpack config here
       */
      extend(config, ctx) {
        config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
        if (ctx.isDev)
          config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      },
      postcss: {
        plugins: {
          'postcss-import': {},
          'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
          'tailwindcss': {},
          'autoprefixer': {},
        },
      },
      transpile: ['@passionatepeople/sanity-utils', 'vue-pincode-input'],
    },
    generate: {
      interval: 200,
      routes: async() => {
        if (!process.env.STATIC_HOST) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error('No STATIC_HOST variable specified!')
          process.exit(1)
        }
        await getSitePayload(process.env.STATIC_HOST)
        const { pages } = require('./dist/data.json')
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('Explicit routes to generate:')
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        pages.forEach(({ route }) => console.log(` - ${route}`))
        return pages
      },
      fallback: true,
    },
    purgeCSS: {
      paths: [
        'components/**/*.vue',
        'layouts/**/*.vue',
        'pages/**/*.vue',
        'plugins/**/*.js',
        'dist/*.json',
      ],
      whitelistPatterns: [/bg-/, /text-/, /from-/, /to-/, /border-/, /lyt-/, /w-/, /grid-cols-/],
      extractors: [
        {
          extractor(content) {
            return content.match(/[\w-.:!/]+(?<!:)/g)
          },
          extensions: ['html', 'vue', 'js', 'json'],
        },
      ],
    },
    /*
     ** Storybook module configuration
     ** See https://storybook.nuxtjs.org/options/
     */
    storybook: {
      addons: ['@storybook/addon-controls/register', '@storybook/addon-viewport/register'],
    },
    watchers: {
      webpack: {
        ignored: [
          '**/*.{md,log,prettierignore,prettierrc,stylelintignore,npmrc,gitignore}',
          '**/.git/**',
        ],
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Quite a simple debugging, download the project into a new directory, extract your project there (from the `.zip`) and try to run it again. That way, no git involved. Be sure that this is not working from the service worker, trying that into a private window of some other browser (like Firefox) may help. Create a new static page with nothing in it, whitelist it from the auth module and see if this happens again. Trying to reach this page should also remove any kind of middleware/plugins/side effect-y code that you may not have spotted (yet). Finally, ask a colleague if the same is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

The actual issue was actually a version bump of ESlint from `1.x.x` to `3.x.x`. `git bisect` helped finding out the actual culprit!

---

Cloning the repo again and reinstalling the dependencies again, fixed all the above mentioned issues while running `yarn dev`!